# Rust SDL2 - Correct PixelFormatEnum Value for an RGBA Array?

Tags: rust, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to use the [sdl2](https://crates.io/crates/sdl2) crate in rust, to create an image on the CPU pixel-by-pixel, and then draw that image to the window.
I already figured out how to do all of that, except for one small detail: choosing the correct [`PixelFormatEnum`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/pixels/enum.PixelFormatEnum.html) when creating my [`Surface`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/surface/struct.Surface.html).

I have a function that generates my image as a `Vec<u8>`, which generates the bytes in the order `R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A, ...` regardless of endianness, because it generates the bytes individually, and not in whole pixels.
I then create a `Surface`, and copy those bytes into it.
My question is, which `PixelFormatEnum` is the correct one in this case?

There are 4 candidates: `PixelFormatEnum::RGBA8888`, `PixelFormatEnum::ABGR8888`, `PixelFormatEnum::RGBA32`, and `PixelFormatEnum::ABGR32`.
`RGBA8888` and `ABGR8888` are actual variants of this enum, whereas `RGBA32` and `ABGR32` are aliases for the former two, that change which variant they alias based on `cfg(target_endian)`.

Since I want to draw the image correctly regardless of endianness, it might seem like I should pick one of the `8888` variants, but I'm not sure this is actually correct, because a comment on the definition of the `32` aliases reads "[`// Endianness-agnostic aliases for 32-bit formats`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/src/sdl2/pixels.rs.html#253)".
This seems to suggest that maybe the `32` aliases are the actual ones that won't change behavior based on endianness? I'm confused...

On my little-endian windows system, both `ABGR8888` and `RGBA32` work correctly, while the other two interpret the color channels in reverse. Unfortunately I don't have a big-endian system, so I can't find the answer by testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case you should pick `PixelFormatEnum::RGBA8888`

On the other hand, `PixelFormatEnum::RGBA32` is useful when your want to use a framebuffer of type like `[u32; X]` (`Vec<u32>`, etc; where `u32` represents a whole pixel) *directly* and don't want to worry about endianness of said `u32`'s. 
(`PixelFormatEnum::RGBA32` is the same as `PixelFormatEnum::RGBA8888` on big endian systems, and the same as `PixelFormatEnum::ABGR8888` on little-endian ones.)

Comment: `RGBA8888` interprets colors in reverse for me. `ABGR8888` actually works for me, so that's why I'm confused